# Postgres LIKE ALL with Spring Data JPA

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I was using below query on my Spring Boot project and it was working well.

```
    @Query  ("SELECT b.belgeKok FROM BelgeEntity b WHERE (b.evrakTurId = ?1 OR ?1 = 0) AND (b.firmaId = ?2 OR ?2 = 0) AND (b.kategoriId = ?3 OR ?3 = 0) "
        + "AND (b.belgeTurId = ?4 OR ?4 = 0) AND (b.projeId = ?5 OR ?5 = 0) AND (b.aciklama LIKE %?6% OR ?6 = '') AND (b.ocr LIKE %?7% OR ?7 = '')")
    public List<String> findByCustomQuery(Integer et, Integer firma, Integer kategori, Integer belgeTur, Integer proje, String aciklama, String kelime1);
```

Now i need to search for more than one word for one column and need to use Postgres LIKE ALL query with an array list as parameter.

First of all is there a way to use LIKE ALL query in @Query annotation?
I googled for it but coulnt find anything.

When i try the below query it gives syntax error as below

```
   @Query (value="SELECT b.belgeKok FROM BelgeEntity b WHERE (b.evrakTurId = ?1 OR ?1 = 0) AND (b.firmaId = ?2 OR ?2 = 0) AND (b.kategoriId = ?3 OR ?3 = 0) "
          + "AND (b.belgeTurId = ?4 OR ?4 = 0) AND (b.projeId = ?5 OR ?5 = 0) AND (b.aciklama LIKE %?6% OR ?6 = '') AND (b.ocr LIKE ALL ?7 OR ?7 = '')", nativeQuery = true)
   public List<String> findByCustomQuery(Integer et, Integer firma, Integer kategori, Integer belgeTur, Integer proje, String aciklama, Set<String> kelime1);
```

> 15:51:25.790 [http-nio-8888-exec-7] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
>   15:51:25.790 [http-nio-8888-exec-7] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
>     Position: 267
>   15:51:25.805 [http-nio-8888-exec-7] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
>     Position: 267

When i try this: (b.ocr LIKE ALL '?7' OR ?7 = '')
it gives syntax error at or near "'(:x7_0_, :x7_1_)'"

Many thanks in advance!
Murat

Comment: you can use regular expression in postges like this i think. wont put it as an answer as i dont have something in front of me to test but try 

 b.ocr ~ '?7|""'

Comment: in postgre i can get what i want with following query: select * from public.belge where ocr like all ('{"%23%","%protokol%","%t.c.%"}') i want to get this from Spring data jpa side. if i can get same result with reg ex i want to give it a try. but i couldnt get correct results with ~ yet. Could you pls tell me relevant query with ~